# How to create a view referencing itself (recursive)

Tags: sql, database, view, mariadb

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id   |   fx   |   value
```

I need to create a view with the following columns:

```
id   |   fx   |   value  |   amount  |   updatedFx   |   updatedValue   |  updatedAmount
```

amount = value * fx -> no problem, working;

updatedFx = a value I get from another table with query -> no problem, working;

updatedValue = a value I get from another table with query -> no problem, working;

updatedAmount = I need to make this column the updatedFx * updatedValue of this view.

The problem is that I don't want to query again the other tables, just like I did for the previous columns... Is there a way I can reference this view, so I can do something like this.updatedFx * this.updatedValue.

I think I need to make it recursive somehow, but I never really used it and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Edit question to provide schema with sample data as text tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can name each column in a table expression and then use them in the main query to compute the value(s) you want. For example:

```
create view v as
select *, updatedFx * updatedValue as updatedAmount
from (
  select
    id,
    fx,
    value,
    value * fx as amount,
    (my formula) as updateFx,
    (my formula) as updateValue
  from ...
) x
```

The table expression produces the columns `updatedFx` and `updatedValue`. Then it's easy to use them in the main query.